# "DLL load failed" when using mercurial on trac

Tags: python, apache, mercurial, mod-wsgi, trac

My mercurial repository works correctly in trac when I use the `tracd` server.

However, when I use `apache`, I get the following warning at the top of all trac pages:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with
>   repository "(default)" (Unsupported
>   version control system "hg": DLL load
>   failed: The specified module could not
>   be found.). Look in the Trac log for
>   more information.

The trac log doesn't have anything useful except a warning about mercurial being compiled with Python 2.6.2 and the actual version of Python running being 2.6.4.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Versions:

- Python 2.6 (binary installer from python.org)
- trac 0.12.2 (using easy_install)
- mercurial (the [Windows pre-built binary from tortoisehg](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/mercurial-1.7.5.win32-py2.6.exe))

Apache is running on a Windows XP (32-bit) machine for testing. I have admin rights, but I think that apache is running as `Local User`.

Comment: Could it be related to this similar bug that lots of people have experienced when using svn + trac http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/6739

Comment: Do you have your Trac log level set to `DEBUG`?

Comment: Also having this same problem, and would love to see a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. There is no problem in mercurial package version [1.7.1](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/mercurial-1.7.1.win32-py2.6.exe). The mistake appears in higher versions, up to 1.8.

Comment: It still happens with Mercurial 2.2, and Trac 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error when setting up hgweb (no trac). Hopefully this helps you and anyone else doing the same thing and finding this question via Google.

I solved the problem by using the python library mercurial installer instead of the normal windows msi (or tortoisehg) installer ("Mercurial-1.8.1 (32-bit py2.6)" from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) and ensuring the mercurial libs import line in hgweb.cgi is commented out.